# How to permute 2 same sized arrays using same permutation in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, permutation

If I have two bash arrays `a=(1 2 3 4 5)` and `b=(12 23 21 2 3)`. I need to permute them such that if after permutation, 1 in array `a` goes to 3rd position then 12 in array `b` should also go to 3rd position.

EDIT: To make my question clearer. I will try to explain what I am trying to do. 
I have to shuffle elements of an array randomly, so that position of the elements changes. 
Then, I am given another array of the same size as the first array.I need to shuffle the elements of the second array as the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this using `shuf` shell command (coreutils) to shuffle an array :

```
$ a=(0 1 2 3 4 5) c=0
$ for i in $(shuf -i 0-$(( ${#a[@]} -1)) ); do b[i]=${a[c++]}; done
$ echo ${b[@]}
2 1 3 0 4 5
```

Answer (score -1):

if a indices are always 1..5 then this should work

```
b=(${b[a[1-1]-1]} ${b[a[2-1]-1]} ${b[a[3-1]-1]} ${b[a[4-1]-1]} ${b[a[5-1]-1]})
```

it will be easier if a was indexed 0..4 :

```
b=(${b[a[0]]} ${b[a[1]]} ${b[a[2]]} ${b[a[3]]} ${b[a[4]]})
```

Otherwise it will be useful to create a third array p for example :
Where p is a permutation of {0..$((n-1))}

```
p=(3 0 1 2 4)
a=(${a[p[0]]} ${a[p[1]]} ${a[p[2]]} ${a[p[3]]} ${a[p[4]]})
b=(${b[p[0]]} ${b[p[1]]} ${b[p[2]]} ${b[p[3]]} ${b[p[4]]})
```

If arrays can be arbitrary sized

```
atmp=("${a[@]}")
btmp=("${b[@]}")
for ((i=0;i<n;i++)); do
    a[i]=${atmp[p[i]]}
    b[i]=${btmp[p[i]]}
done
```

Remark this can change the direction of permutation :

```
atmp=("${a[@]}")
btmp=("${b[@]}")
for ((i=0;i<n;i++)); do
    a[p[i]]=${atmp[i]}
    b[p[i]]=${btmp[i]}
done
```

Comment: Thanks, but the arrays could be arbitrarily sized. I was looking for a general method which works for any array size!